# How do you find the subject with two groups and a who after it?

Tags: who, compound-subjects

O George, the man of the year, who [IS or ARE] the bright spot of the world, lead us by your example!

A friend said *George* is the subject and therefore it should be IS.  I say *Who* which becomes You and so it should be ARE.  Help please!

Comment: I think you need to clarify the sentence. Is it a question for George or a statement about George?

Comment: George is the man of the year who is whatever. O George, you are the man of the year. Does that fix it?

Answer (score -1):

There are two issues here: number and person.

The number of the relative pronoun "who" should be the same as the number of its referent, which is either "George" or "man" (either is possible). Because "George" and "man" are singular, "who" should be singular.

The person is determined by the meaning of the sentence. If the speaker were extolling the virtues of some distant man, then the verb should be in the third person:

> O George, the man of the year, who is the bright spot of the world!

If the speaker were talking directly to George, then the verb should be in the second person:

> O George, the man of the year, who are the bright spot of the world!

Note that this explanation follows traditional English grammar rules; actual usage can vary. (The version with "are", in particular, would sound unusual to many people.)

Also, I changed the terminal punctuation because there did not seem to be any question.

Comment: Surely 'O George' mandates that George be the addressee? A comma is needed if 'O' is just an unattached exclamation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps it's an Americanism, but I've heard people use "O" otherwise. E.g.: "I just saw your cat on the street chasing pigeons." "O that cat, he's always getting into trouble." (Or "O Mr. Mittens, ...") I'd be curious to find out how common that usage is.

Comment: 'O[h] that cat!' may or may not take the comma after the first word. It stands as a sensible fragment. But here, while using a comma after 'O' sets it off as the sole pragmatic marker (attention grabber), leaving it out makes 'O George' the intensified  vocative.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I believe that the use I am describing is pretty well attested. E.g.: https://whitmanarchive.org/published/LG/1881/poems/90 (Whitman is a bit dated, but plenty of other examples exist.)

Comment: Lyrics and poems are a law unto themselves. [ProWritingAid](https://prowritingaid.com/grammar/1000160/Should-I-use-comma-after-interjections-#:~:text=When%20interjections%20are%20used%20at,a%20unique%20part%20of%20speech.&text=They%20can%20also%20be%20used%20at%20the%20beginning%20or%20in,put%20commas%20after%20the%20interjections.) gives the traditional rule 'use a comma after an interjection' ('Oh, I don’t care where we go.' / 'Oh well, it’s his loss.' ...) Unless used to call George's attention, the interjection ends at 'O'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh, well, I guess I take a more descriptivist approach in this case. That’s fairly unusual for me! :)

Comment: I'd read this as << O George, you who are the man of the year, who are the bright spot of the world ... lead us by your example! >> If I really had to read it.